# TypeError: object of type 'Stack' has no len()

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

"So I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. For the code I need to store all the elements, and remove them from the stack one by one and then display the size of the stack. I need to use the pop method, push method, and size method. So far I haven't gotten any luck. Also, I need to define a stack that will take int as well."

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self):
    self.stack=[]
def empty(self):
    if self.stack==[]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Push(self, dataval):
    if dataval not in self.stack:
        self.stack.append(dataval)
        top=len(self)-1

def Pop(self):
    if empty(self):
        print('Empty')
    else:
        dataval=self.stack.pop()
    if len(self.stack)==0:
        top=None
        return ('No books are on stack.')
    else:
        top=len(self.stack)
        print("Popped item is"+str(dataval))
def Display(self):
    if empty(self):
        print('Stack is empty')
    else:
        top=len(self.stack)-1
        print('BookIDs in stack are: ')
        for i in range(top,-1,-1):
            print(str(self[i]))
if __name__=="__main__":
stack=Stack()
top=None
stack.Push(1000)
Push(2000)
Push(3000)
Push(4000)
Pop(self.stack)
Display(self.stack)
Pop(self.stack)
Display(self.stack)
Pop(self.stack)
Display(self.stack)
Pop(self.stack)
Display(self.stack)
```

Comment: Look at the line the traceback is pointing at, the one where you try to call `len(self)`. Did you ever actually implement `len(self)` functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in this function

```
def Push(self, dataval):
    if dataval not in self.stack:
        self.stack.append(dataval)
        top=len(self)-1       --------------- > len(self) is the error.
```

It needs to be len(self.stack)